# Alternatives to SLF4J MDC

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm trying to log the user name initiating each request in my JSF application, however apparently [MDC on a web app server (thread pool) is risky](http://ashtonkemerling.com/blog/2017/09/01/mdc-and-threadpools/).

I've already seen MDC leaking out into a new call when using the EJB @Asynchronous call which I wouldn't have expected.

What are the alternatives? I'd rather not have to rely on remembering to put the username on every log call. Do I wrap slf4j?

Comment: It's not at all risky - at least no more risky that running a web server - just do it right. Again, much like running a web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BoristheSpider do you have any links for how to do it right? Are there any other tips you have beyond what's in https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your MDC put(..) with remove(..) in a try-finally block

```
MDC.put("system", "fedora");
try {
    // your code here
} finally {
    MDC.remove("system");
}
```

so that no state is kept after your code has run.